# FOR will SET a variable in command line, but not inside a Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, variables, command-line

I have the following batch file contents:

```
REM Newest folder
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR \\cc_server\CruiseControl\TFS_Root\Release\2017.V1\Deploy\Store\Company\MyApp\* /B /O:D /AD') DO SET NewestDir=%%I
REM Newest file of newest folder
IF Defined NewestDir (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR "\\cc_server\CruiseControl\TFS_Root\Release\2017.V1\Deploy\Store\Company\MyApp\%NewestDir%\[RL]*[x64]*[SuperPro]*.7z" "\\cc_server\CruiseControl\TFS_Root\Release\2017.V1\Deploy\Store\Company\MyApp\%NewestDir%\[RL]*[x64]*[SuperPro]*.zip" /B /O:D /A-D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
    IF Defined NewestFile (
        SET ExistsInStore=TRUE
    )
) ELSE (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR \\backups\Builds\Release\2017.V1\MyApp\* /B /O:D /AD') DO SET NewestDir=%%I
    IF Defined NewestDir (
         FOR /F "delims=" %%J IN ('DIR \\backups\Builds\Release\2017.V1\MyApp\%NewestDir%\[RL]*[x64]*[SuperPro]*.7z \\backups\Builds\Release\2017.V1\MyApp\%NewestDir%\[RL]*[x64]*[SuperPro]*.zip /B /O:D /A-D') DO SET NewestFile=%%J
         PAUSE
    )
)

IF Defined NewestFile (
    IF Defined ExistsInStore (
        copy "\\cc_server\CruiseControl\TFS_Root\Release\2017.V1\Deploy\Store\Company\MyApp\%NewestDir%\%NewestFile%" .
    ) ELSE (

        copy "\\backups\Builds\Release\2017.V1\MyApp\%NewestDir%\%NewestFile%" .
    )

    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x "%NewestFile%" -o"MyApp 2017"
    del "%NewestFile%"
)


Set NewestDir=
SET NewestFile=
SET ExistsInStore=
```

Given it does not exist the file in in `cc_server` it then falls through the `backups` machine where it exists.

The problem is: if I run the script, I will see a whole bunch of
`SET NewestDir=` lines, and after:

```
File Not Found
Press any key to continue . . .
```

which corresponds to the `PAUSE` command line.

I know the files exist there, as the next paragraph will make it clear.

If I copy the instructions of the relevant part and replace the `%%` occurrences by `%` as follows:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %I IN ('DIR \\backups\Builds\Release\2017.V1\MyApp\* /B /O:D /AD') DO SET NewestDir=%I
IF Defined NewestDir (
     FOR /F "delims=" %J IN ('DIR \\backups\Builds\Release\2017.V1\MyApp\%NewestDir%\[RL]*[x64]*[SuperPro]*.7z \\backups\Builds\Release\2017.V1\MyApp\%NewestDir%\[RL]*[x64]*[SuperPro]*.zip /B /O:D /A-D') DO SET NewestFile=%J
)
```

and run it directly in the command prompt, the problem does not occur, and the `NewestFile` variable will be set.

What am I wrong doing?

Comment: Take a look at [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), which is required here as you write *and* read the same variables within the same block of code...

Comment: @aschipfl: Is that the reason why "my" script is in two separate `IF` blocks instead of them being nested?

Comment: I don't think so; your script is nested with respect to variables; for instance, in the `else` branch of your first `if`/`else` block you set `NewestDir` and you read it as `%NewestDir%`; however, `if defined` can be used without problems...